# I didn't make any transfers on my metamask

Tags: transactions, ether, metamask

I deposited some eth to my metamask some days ago and need to wait for my Gemini account to confirm. But the next day noticed my account was at 1 dollar. I didn't touch anything nor send anything. what do I do?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Need more information in the question, but given what I see:

> a. Assuming txn "0xf295..." is the deposit txn you are referring to
> Gemini->Metamask

- Whoever withdrew the funds (most likely owner of account "0x61fed..") has your private keys/ secret word of your metamask account or has access to your computer and knows your metamask password
- You can click the link address on the address "0x61fed.." to see further where the trail goes, but you cannot recover it

> b. Assuming txn "0xf295..." is NOT the deposit txn you are referring
> to (as it has come from KuCoin)

- No funds were sent into this metamask account from Gemini account
- Your funds should still be secure with Gemini and the transaction failed at their end
- Reach out to their support team and they should re-process the withdrawal or reallocate the balance to your Gemini account.